# Equivalence relation $\mathscr R$ from the size of equivalence classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

**Question:**
"Let $\mathscr R$ be an equivalence relation on a set $\mathcal A$ with exactly 4 equivalence classes, namely $\mathcal A_1$, $\mathcal A_2$, $\mathcal A_3$, and $\mathcal A_4$ such that $|\mathcal A_1| = |\mathcal A_2| = 10$ and $|\mathcal A_3| = |\mathcal A_4| = 5$. Determine $\mathscr R$."

============================================

This is a review question for my discrete math course, and I'm honestly not even sure where to start.

There's no knowledge given about the set $\mathcal A$ other than it has $30$ elements (obtained from the sizes of the equivalence classes), so I'm not sure how it is possible to determine anything about the relation $\mathscr R$.

I thought about relabeling the elements of $\mathcal A_1$ to $\mathcal A_4$ as $a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_{30} $, then determining the individual elements of $\mathscr R$, but that doesn't make sense as a solution to this question. Am I missing something?

**I'm not looking for any solutions, just a push in the right direction.**

Comment: Welcome to math.se. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a formatting guide.

Comment: Are you sure the question is not "determine the number of relations satisfying these conditions?"

Answer (score 1):

R = $\cup${ A$_j$ × A$_j$ : j = 1,2,3,4 }.

Exercise.  Show that there is a bijection between the equivalence relations of a set and the partitions of that set such that the equivalence classes of the relation are sets of the partition.